# Apache ProxyPass HTTP does not work with SSL

Tags: apache, ssl, reverse-proxy, virtualhost, proxypass

I was trying to add cloudflare SSL certification to the website I host locally, and force HTTPS for all users.

Connecting to `IP:80` works fine (from inside my network). `IP:443` fails as it expects a SSL certificate. Accessing `domainname.com` tells me the site is secure, so the SSL certificate works. But whenever I access it this way, the proxy website doesn't, displaying the 'Apache2 Default Page'. Same with connecting to `IP:80` outside the network, it fails to proxy pass.

This is the config file I have setup, and by running `apachectl -S` I checked that no other rules exist.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName name.com:80

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:7000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:7000/
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName name.com:443

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/cloudflare/name.com.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/cloudflare/name.com.key

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:7000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:7000/
</VirtualHost>
```

Is this because I am trying to load an http website, even though it is local? And if this is true, how else can I solve this problem? I feel so close, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, by switching to the default-ssl config file provided with Apache2, and removing my version the issue resolved itself. Not sure why it worked the second time I tried it but oh well.